# How to get last login time of a user in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

How do I find out the last login time of a user when they log into their Gmail account?

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you say *"their Gmail account"* you actually mean your account. You cannot find out about other users last login time or activity.

### To see the latest activity of your Gmail account

1. On the main screen find at the far bottom right part of the page the `Details` link and click on it.
2. A pop-up window will appear with **the account's** latest activity.

[image: latest activity Gmail]